# Implementing randomness for physics (like in Blender)

Tags: java, game-physics, physics, blender

I am referring, as an example, to Blender's particle collision system, where you can set the randomness for particle damping between 0.0 and 1.0.
My question now is: how does it exactly work? Yes, there will be a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 but how is it applied to the damping factor? I want to create something similar in Java and therefore I want to fully understand the calculation behind that. Is the random factor the probability p and the calculation something like a gaussian distribution?
As an application example: I want to randomize the direction of a vector.

`vector.y += random1; vector.y += random2; vector.z += random3; vector.scale(prevLength/vector.length);`

However, it might appear, that all vector components become zero, it's very unlikely but not impossible. So clearly this is not the right solution.

Comment: Sounds more like a math question. Actually, it sounds like something you should ask on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: mh, maybe... on the other hand my goal is to implement it in java...

Comment: why is it closed? I am asking for the theory of applying the randomness on the factor. In what sense was it not focused enough?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but probably because *"the theory of applying the randomness on the factor"* is not a specific programming question.

Comment: HI, If you need help with the theory, this should not be asked on Stack Overflow (Math might be a better place?). If you have questions regarding the Java implementation or some specific issue with your Java code, update your question with code examples for how to reproduce the issues and we will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer for the damping

```
public Vector3f damping(Vector3f vector) 
{
    float random = (float) (this.randomDamp*(Math.random()*2-1));
    float clampedValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (1-damp)+random)); //clamp between 0 and 1
    vector.scale(clampedValue);
    return vector;
}
```

It appears so that blender just adds the random number so with a factor of 0.5 and a random factor of 1, the final factor will vary between -0.5 (0) and 1.5 (1).